# When to transform predictors in regression when response may be quadratic?

Tags: regression, data-transformation, predictor

I am analyzing data from an experiment in which treatment levels increase quadratically, e.g. the treatment levels are $0, 1, 4, 9$.

When analyzing the response using regression, would it make sense to use the square root of the treatment level as a predictor?

If so, how would this affect interpretation?

Answer (score 10):

When you don't know the functional form ahead of time (which is a common setting) and you have no reason to assume it's linear, it's best to be flexible.  If there were more levels of treatment you could fit a quadratic or restricted cubic spline shape, for example.  For only 4 levels it may be best to assign 3 degrees of freedom to treatment using 3 dummy variables.

Comment: thanks for your answer. Could you explain what you mean by 'assigning 3 degrees of freedom to treatment using 3 dummy variables'?

Comment: is that the same as performing an ANOVA?

Comment: Yes, this is ANOVA if there are no covariates to adjust for and if one is willing to assume normality and equal group variances.  Had there been more levels it would have been better to model the profile over levels using a smooth fit (e.g., quadratic).

Comment: that is a good point. instead of using 6 reps at each of four levels, 3 reps at each of eight levels... will keep that in mind for future. Is it necessarily inappropriate to fit a quadratic or other two parameter non-linear model through four points?

Comment: No it's not inappropriate, it just assumes a quadratic shape.  It requires 3 parameters whereas the most flexible mean model with 4 treatments requires the same number.

Answer (score 9):

Why not look at a bivariate X-Y scatterplot in advance of running a regression.  That'll show you the shape of the line or curve, especially if you have software that can give a lowess/loess fit (locally weighted smoothed fit).

As to interpretation, it'll no doubt be easier for you than for your audience, but if you do have a quadratic fit, then for each increment of one on the sq. rt. of X, Y will change by b, your coefficient.

If you really only have 4 levels of X, I agree with @Frank's point and would add that you might make your job easier by running an ANOVA instead of regression.  Or, some software makes it easy to combine continuous and categorical predictors, fusing regression and anova into a general linear model without the need for dummy variables (if you use SPSS, search 'Unianova').

Comment: Running an initial look at the relationship outside of the formal analysis will get the d.f. wrong, resulting in inaccurate confidence interval coverage.  A good regression text will describe how dummy variables are constructed.  Good software packages do this automatically if you make them sense that treatment is a categorical variable.

Comment: @Frank Harrell, d.f. is density function? I liked @rolando2 answer, and would add one question to to you, @David: Did you choose the treatment values (for theoretical reasons, for instance) or somehow the treatment is produced by some process beyond your control?

Comment: @Frank - Wouldn't concern for accurate coefficient confidence intervals come after model-building and thus after determining whether a particular X-Y relationship is linear?

Comment: Not at all.  It needs to be an explicit part of model building.  Otherwise a simple bootstrap or Monte Carlo simulation would show that when you claim 0.95 confidence interval coverage (or compute P-values) the actual coverage is much less than that.  A classic paper on this topic is @ARTICLE{gra91,
  author = {Grambsch, P. M. and {O'Brien}, P. C.},
  year = 1991,
  title = {The effects of transformations and preliminary tests for
          non-linearity in regression},
  journal = Stat in Med,
  volume = 10,
  pages = {697-709}
}
d.f. = degrees of freedom.

Comment: @rolando If I understand ANOVA correctly, it requires that the four treatments are independent factors, whereas in this case the treatments are points along a continuous variable.

Comment: @David - 0, 1, 4, and 9 are each a level of the single treatment variable.  In ANOVA you would test whether the mean is the same across each of these 4 levels.  Your comment seems to apply to a situation that doesn't apply here, in which you had 4 different predictor variables (e.g., sex, ethnicity, income, and region).

Comment: @rolando, I guess my question was whether it is appropriate to compare the levels using ANOVA instead of regression

Comment: Yes, in your case I believe it amounts to the same thing.  Regression with dummy variables can be equivalent to ANOVA.  They're both subsumed under what's called the General Linear Model.

Comment: @David then please restate the question, it gets more unclear the more I read through this. I tried to fix up the title, but it's a moving target.